# force https protocol

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, https, centos

How do I enforce my website to use `https://` in the entire site? My site was built using CodeIgniter, MySQL, & Apache on CentOS, can anyone please enlighten me.

**EDIT**:

I am using CodeIgniter, it has this .htaccess. as I mentioned on my comment below, I wanna do the reverse (forcing `https` on some parts of the website):

The `.htaccess` on my system:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If I add what @Dale suggested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ^(login|register|userportal)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I get response **500**. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used this in the past, in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

There may be better implementations but it's always worked for me

If you want to remove the www part I've used this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here's the combined rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This deals with the protocol first and then removes the w's

Update:

To enforce https protocol for particular directories you could use something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ^(login|register|userportal)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You would of course remove this (below) if you use the above

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Is there any adjustment to be made here, in case I want to force www.site.com to site.com? Still, in `https` protocol?

Comment: what if I do the inverse? I only want to force https on some URL, say for example http://mysite.com/login, http://mysite.com/register, & http://mysite.com/userportal and its segments (userportal/profile, userportal/logout)? Thanks!

Comment: @fishcracker Added a bit more, might need a bit of playing with

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter, it has built in `.htaccess` when I added your suggestion I get response 500 :(, please see my edit.